# Covering space of a $3$-manifold with infinite fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

For a $3$-manifold $X$, s.t. $\pi_1(X)$ is infinite, how to see the universal covering space of $X$, $\tilde{X}$ is a non-compact $3$-manifold and $H_3(\tilde{X})=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $X$ is intended to be connected.  If $x\in X$ and $p:\tilde{X}\to X$ is the covering map, then $p^{-1}(\{x\})$ is closed in $\tilde{X}$, discrete (since $p$ is a covering map), and in bijection with $\pi_1(X)$.  This means $\tilde{X}$ is not compact, since it has a closed subset which is not compact.  The fact that $H_3(\tilde{X})=0$ then follows from the fact that $\tilde{X}$ is a noncompact connected $3$-manifold (see for instance Proposition 3.29 of [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html)).

Comment: Eric: is it that $H_3(X)=0$ means that $X$ is nonorientable?

Comment: @janmarqz An orientation is a nonzero section of the bundle of local orientations $M_{\mathbb{Z}}$ (defined in the chapter Eric cites), and for compact orientable manifolds a section can be represented by an element of $H_3(X)$ (a *fundamental class*).  Since cycles have compact image, for a noncompact manifold there is a point outside this image, implying there is a point of the corresponding section that is zero, so it must be exactly the zero section and thus the cycle is nullhomologous.  Hence $H_3(X)=0$ means that $X$ is either nonorientable or noncompact.

Comment: merci beaucoup Kyle